# circular dependency in declarations C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to make a structure that is a container for a dequeue. In order it can perform pop, push, and other actions it needs to contain function pointers to be able to call them passing itself as an argument to them. I'm stuck

If I declare the functions first the compiler can't identify the struct I'm trying to pass to it.
While if I declare the struct first the pointers to the functions give an error as the functions haven't been declared yet.

How would I go about fixing this circular dependency?

Obviously there would be more to this once I figure out how to get these to work properly I just wanted to get an instance of A function that could be called without a problem occurring.

```
template <class T>
T pop_front(Deque&);

template<typename T>
struct Deque 
{
    int length = 2;
    int head = 0;
    int tail = 1;
    T pop_front = (*functocall)(this);
};

template<class T>
T pop_front(Deque &a)
{
    T x = NULL;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: predeclare the struct with `template <typename T> struct Deque;`?

Comment: Are you trying to declare a member function?

Comment: Hint: forward declarations.

Comment: In C++ structs can have member functions, no need to use C-style "OOP" with function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to predeclare something (or, better, everything).

```
template <typename T> struct Deque; // important. now the pop_front declaration knows about Deque.

template <typename T>
T pop_front(Deque&);

template<typename T>
struct Deque 
{
    int length = 2;
    int head = 0;
    int tail = 1;
    T pop_front = (*functocall)(this);
};

template<typename T>
T pop_front(Deque &a)
{
    T x = NULL;
    return x;
}
```

I'd also recommend that you be consistent with `typename` and `class`...

Additionally, consider just defining a method. You can do that in structs in C++.